# Laravel Homestead , Socket.io Connection Refused

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, socket.io, homestead

I`m using laravel Event broadcasting , socket.io , node.js , and redis to pass notifications to the client side in real time.

The code is fairly simple, when i make a get request to '/' on the server an event will be fired and some data will be broadcast to all browsers(client side) which listening to this event on a channel(test-Channel).

The Routes.php content:

```
Route::get('/', 'uses' => function () {

    Event::fire( new App\Events\UserHasRegistered('DummyData') );

    return view('test');
}]);
```

The UserHasRegistered Event class :

```
class UserHasRegistered extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $name;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name){
        $this->name =  $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn(){
        return ['test-channel'];
    }

}
```

The node Server file content :

```
/*General Configurations :
- Setting up the node Server 
- Server side Socket.io 
- node js Redis Client 
- instance of ioredis 
*/
var server  =  require('http').Server();
var io      =  require('socket.io')(server);
var Redis   =  require('ioredis');
var redis   =  new Redis();

/*listen to a channel , and when a Message Arrives we send it to All Listening clients via socket.io*/
redis.subscribe('test-channel');
redis.on('message' , function(channel , message){
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    // The Client Side Channel naming conversion => channelName:EventPublishedToServer => testChannel:UserHasRegistered
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event , message.data );
});

/*Booting Up the Server : port 3000 */
server.listen(3000 , function(){
    console.log('The Server Is Running');
});
```

Every thing is working fine and the data is passed to the the node server through redis but on the client side where i use socket.io to listen to a specific channel , i get this weird error

> GET http://192.168.10.10:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1446018378941-633 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The Client side :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        /*Homestead IP Address , Port:3000 Node Server Port*/
        var socket = io('http://192.168.10.10:3000');

        /*When Data is sent to client side*/
        socket.on('test-channel:App\\Events\\UserHasRegistered' , function(data){
            console.log(data);
            //$('ul').append('<li><h5>'+ data.name +'</h5></li>');
        });
    </script>
```

> I`m Using Windows 10 and Homestead virtual box.

any Help ?

Comment: Hey op, check the second answer, that's the right one! Be sure to mark it so you can help others like it helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had this same issue and i solved it opening port 3000 in VirtualBox. For that, you should go into homestead settings inside adn then Network->Port Forwarding and there put 3000 on both ports.

Comment: How do i do this?\

Comment: Hi @JordyGroote , at least on a Windows machine, open VirtualBox, select your homestead machine, click on settings, then Network, click on Advanced, select Port Forwarding, and finally add a new tcp rule, with Host Port with 3000 and Guest Port with 3000 as well.  
Tell me if you had any issues.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to ssh by "vagrant ssh" to your virtual machine and start your server-file from there? A had the same problem while i was starting my server file from windows- or git-command

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    /*Homestead IP Address , Port:3000 Node Server Port*/
    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.10.10:3000');

    /*When Data is sent to client side*/
    socket.on('test-channel:App\\Events\\UserHasRegistered' , function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //$('ul').append('<li><h5>'+ data.name +'</h5></li>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes , i did .. still no luck , i think it`s something with the homestead and nodejs server ports because i did run this code outside homestead using WAMP , and it did work so nothing wrong with the code